# Remove 0xff from the end of a binary flash image using bash script

Tags: bash, makefile, cygwin, binaryfiles

I have a tool that generates a 32MB binary image to be written to a flash memory.
But only the first 2MB contains valuable data, the rest is just 0xff.
So I would like to remove the 0xff bytes from the end of the file using a nice bash / makefile script.
I could use head:

```
head -c 2M test.bin > out.bin
```

But I don't know the actual length, so I would like to find the first occurence of 0xff from the end of the file as input to head or similar.

I'm running my tool from a Makefile on cygwin, so it would be good if it could be executed using standard bash / makefile tools.

Comment: Can there be a `0xff` in your valid data, or are you sure it is only present in the last ~30 MB ?

Comment: what is the problem to use `dd` and copy just the first 2MB data ?

Comment: The file could be anything between 2MB and 4MB. 4MB takes a lot longer to program into my relatively slow device.It can contain 0xff in the beginning and middle that should remain untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counting the number of `0xFF` bytes at the end of your file can be done with a combination of `hexdump` (or `xxd`, `od`...) to convert your binary file in a stream of ASCII hexadecimal values and a text processor like `awk` to do the counting. Example:

```
hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X\n"' test.bin | \
  awk '/FF/ {n += 1} !/FF/ {n = 0} END {print n}'
```

Then, removing that number of bytes from the end of the file can be done using e.g. `dd` or `head`. Example:

```
head -c -$d test.bin > results/test.bin
```

All in all, your Makefile could resemble:

```
OUTDIR  := results
OLDBINS := $(wildcard *.bin)
NEWBINS := $(addprefix $(OUTDIR)/,$(OLDBINS))

.PHONY: all

all: $(NEWBINS)

$(OUTDIR)/%: % | $(OUTDIR)
    n=$$(hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X\n"' $< | \
      awk '/FF/ {n += 1} !/FF/ {n = 0} END {print n}'); \
    head -c -$$n $< > $@

$(OUTDIR):
    mkdir -p $@
```

There are a few make subtleties like [phony targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) ( `all`), [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) (`$<`, `$@`), [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) (`| $(OUTDIR)`), make expansion escaping in recipes (the `$$` signs), make functions (`wildcard`, `addprefix`), a one-line recipe that uses line continuation (the `\` at the end of lines)... But nothing very complicated.

**EDIT**: try to find a faster solution:

Another option may be more efficient (about 20 times faster on 32MB files in my super-simple tests) if the `base64` utility is available and the size of your files is exactly 32MB:

1. `base64`-encode without wrapping:

   ```
    base64 -w0
   ```
2. Use `sed` to remove all trailing `////` strings, followed by a last `//8=` at the end of the file (see [the `base64` RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#page-10)) to understand why these strange trailing texts:

   ```
    sed -E 's#(////)*//8=$##'
   ```
3. `base64`-decode:

   ```
    base64 -d
   ```

One-liner:

```
base64 -w0 test.bin | sed -E 's#(////)*//8=$##' | base64 -d > results/test.bin
```

Note that this may leave one or two `0xFF` characters at the end on the file, depending on the size of the input file and on the number of trailing `0xFF` characters. The new make recipe would be:

```
$(OUTDIR)/%: % | $(OUTDIR)
    base64 -w0 $< | sed -E 's#(////)*//8=$$##' | base64 -d > $@
```

Comment: This seem to do what I need. But since you seem so interested, it's pretty slow, takes 25 s on my 32 MB file. The first sed solution executed in around 1s. But that is OK for me. Thanks  a lot for your help!

Comment: I am not surprised that it is slow and, honestly, personally, I would have written a small C or python program to do the same much faster. It is slow because of the translation from binary to hexadecimal and the byte by byte counting by `awk`. Maybe somebody will come with a faster solution but if you are stuck with standard shell utilities I do not expect miracles.

Comment: Note that if speed is a concern and you have a multi-core computer, the Makefile I propose is parallel safe. Run it as `make -j4`, for instance, for an almost 4 times acceleration on a 4-cores computer. Moreover, the dependencies are correctly expressed: if an input file does not change, the output file will not be re-generated on the next invocations of make.

Comment: Your attempt for a faster solution was actually slower, it took 37s on my 32MB file.

Comment: Gee, I got 0.4 seconds on my computer... Well, this probably comes from significant differences between our computers (memory maybe). By the way, what do you know for sure about your input files? It is not that clear from your question. Are their sizes fixed to 32MB? Do you already know for sure what is the maximum size of the part you want to keep? This could probably be efficiently used to speed-up the whole process.

Answer (score 2):

This sed one liner will operate only on the last line of the file and remove all trailing `0xFF` bytes.

```
sed '$ s/\xff*$//' file > file.out
```

Comment: Using sed, which is a text editor, on binary files is not that straightforward. What you suggest will **not** do what is asked for. For instance, it will delete a series of `0xff` bytes if it is followed by an end-of-line, even if they are not at the end of the file. Using this will very likely damage some binary files...

Comment: I'm afraid that you're wrong about this. This will do exactly what was asked for any file. It will only remove the trailing 0xff bytes regardless of the other raw contents of the file. I tested for this explicitly and I'm updating my answer with those tests showing that it works as intended.

Comment: It worked perfect for the first 100k bytes, but after this it started to remove single occurence of 0xff and change the byte order!
Trying to figure out what the sed script really do, but maybe you can explain.
After hexdump I get the following diff:
Before: 009dd00 0000 f840 45b2 ff2f 9f0a 0e47 0000 0000
After: 009dd00 0000 f840 45b2 0a2f 479f 000e 0000 0000

Comment: Hmm, well I suppose my test that I just added to my solution isn't as robust as I thought. I'm going to try this on a much larger file...

Comment: I tried this on a much larger file and confirmed that it works. I took the file I mentioned in my example and just repeated it over and over until I had a file of 285570 bytes with trailing 0xff bytes. Then I manually removed the trailing bytes and took the md5sum. Finally I used my sed script to remove the bytes and used the md5sum to confirm that the file was identical. Are you positive that you wrote the sed command correctly?

Comment: BTW I am using GNU sed 4.7

Comment: You should try the counter-example I mentioned: a short file with `0xff` followed by newline, followed by anything else.

Comment: You are right. My test file did not have a 0xff followed by a newline. My answer doesn't work.

Comment: @Renauld Pacalet, please review my updated answer and let me know if you can see any issues with it. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it will remove large segments of 0xff in the beginning and middle of the file. My original contains 128 bytes with 0xff in the beginning that gets truncated to 8 bytes of 0xff.

Comment: @Bimme: absolutely, `xxd` outputs several lines and using `sed` still treats these lines as independent. So, lines full of `ff` will be removed even if not at the end of the stream...

Comment: @AKstat: the most important thing to understand with `sed`, in this case, is that the `$` sign in your regular expression stands for **end-of-line**, not **end-of-file**. So, unless you have a single input line, this kind of solution does not work. And `xxd` outputs several lines on large files (do not search the _one-line-output_ option, the maximum length is 256 bytes).

Comment: I really liked this solution and had hoped that there were a sed solution available. A pity it did not work. Thanks a lot for your effort!

Comment: @RenaudPacalet you're absolutely right. I forgot about how xxd inserts new lines. I was up way too late last night when I was working on this. See my edit to remove this issue.

Comment: @Bimme I know you already accepted an answer but if you get a chance to test this I would be very keen to know if it is faster than the other solution on your file.

Comment: @AKstat Your latest solution gives a correct result, but it took 2m50s on my 32MB file. I believe that the conversion to ascii-hex is a big problem, but also all the steps.

Comment: @Bimme I'm actually really surprised by that. On my laptop it took about 7 seconds to execute on a 40MB file that I generated with lots of 0xFF and newlines. However I made a vastly more efficient solution using only sed that only takes half a second for me. Please see my edit and let me know if the performance improves for you.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet what do you think of my revised sed one-liner?

Answer (score 0):

```
head -c -1 test.bin > out.bin
```

The -1 strips the last byte.

Comment: head is not a tool for binary object, moreover he is asking to remove all bytes not just one

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice that he clearly said to remove all bytes. Aside from this, why can't `head` not be used with files which don't necessarily have line terminators in them? I don't see any restriction of this kind in the `head` man-page and would conclude, that the -c option should make sense with every type of file.